# Lottie Compose: how to loop the animation indefinitely

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, lottie

I have the following Lottie animation that plays only once, how can I make it play indefinitely?

```kotlin
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.search_animation))
LottieAnimation(composition = composition)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Update 2023-09-05**
There is an overloaded version of the `LottieAnimation` composable that merges the `LottieAnimation` and `animateLottieCompositionAsState` parameters.

```kotlin
LottieAnimation(
    composition,
    iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever,
)
```

Source: https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android-compose?id=lottieanimation-overload

**Old answer**
You can tell Lottie to iterate an animation forever via the `progress` parameter:

```kotlin
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.search_animation))
val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition = composition, iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever)
LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
    progress = { progress },
)
```

Source: https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android-compose?id=animatelottiecompositionasstate

Answer (score 3):

just to aid those future wanderers that stumble upon this...
These days it's changed to something more like this:

````
LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
    iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever,
    ...
    ```
````

Answer (score -3):

you can just simply add `app:lottie_loop="true"` at your xml for your LottieAnimationView.

Comment: The question is specifically for Compose and not for XML Views.